# Linq query to get the list filtered by max value in one query

Tags: c#, linq

Could you help me to improve this code?

```
var orderNo = "1234";
var maxValue = MyTable.Where(x => x.OrderNo == orderNo )
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Filename)
                      .Select(x => x.Filename)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

var list = (from x in MyTable
            where x.OrderNo == orderNo && x.Filename == maxValue
            select x).Distinct();

list.Dump();
```

Is it possible to improve these 2 Linq queries into 1 and avoiding query 2 times my database. Something like:

```
var list = (from x in MyTable
    where x.OrderNo == orderNo && MaxValue(x.Filename)
    select x)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Is `var1 ` equals to `"1234"` ?

Comment: What are you trying to find? The entry with the "largetst" FileName?

Comment: @Grievoushead yes, sorry I removed var1 and changed it by a hardcoded string.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I'm trying to find the last filename. I assume that my filename can be ordered on the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var list = (
    from x in MyTable
    where x.OrderNo == var1 && 
        x.Filename == MyTable.Where(x => (x.OrderNo == "1234")).Max(p => p.Filename)
    select x
).Distinct();
```

Comment: I like it but this one will generate two queries, right?

Comment: What do you mean by _generate_? If you mean the SQL query that is being generated, then no - it's just one SQL query you get with this.

Comment: I should used the word execute in place of generate

Comment: No it's just one SQL query you pass to your database, which contains a subquery, but it is executed s one query.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `GroupBy`:

```
var list = MyTable
    .Where(x => x.OrderNo == "1234") // or var1
    .GroupBy(x => x.Filename)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .First()
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Why `GroupBy`? Isn't `OrderByDescending` and `First` enough to select the entry with the "maximum" FileName?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: he doesn't want a single record but all distinct rows with this order-number and the "max"-file name.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP wants a list  with matching filename.

Comment: Right. I'm looking for maximum on not for last one because I can get a list of matching filename.

Comment: @B413 seems like this is best fit your needs, isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
MyTable.Where(x => x.OrderNo == "1234")
       .Max(x => x.Filename);
```

You will get all the records that have the maximal filename.